# PyTorch installation problem- package not found using Jupyter notebook and Conda navigator

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, conda

I have tried to install PyTorch using the installation code form official PyTorch website.
I run it locally in the Jupyter notebook on Conda navigator

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

I received the following mistake

```
    PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pytorch
  - cudatoolkit=10.2

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

**What to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use 64-bit Anaconda

`conda` manages packages for one platform and architecture.

It looks like you installed 32-Bit (x86) Win Anaconda version, here:

```sh
- https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-32
```

You can check that channel under that link (https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-32) does not contain any `pytorch` package, and same is for this one: https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch

If you look at the `win64`: https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64 it actually contains `pytorch` packages.

So, there is no `pytorch` `x86` packages in `pytorch` channels and in addition it is not possible to create environment of another architecture, meaning that you need to install 64-bit Anaconda to use `pytorch`.